# Links in the mobile web browser may jump to the Stack Overflow app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, ios-app, stack-overflow-app

I have the Stack Overflow app (and the Stack Exchange app) installed
on an iPhone. When I

- view a SE page of one of my communities *other* than Stack Overflow
  in the mobile web browser (Safari), and
- click on an item in the "Inbox" or "Achievements" popup which 
  refers to a Stack Overflow posting

then the corresponding comment/posting is opened
in the Stack Overflow app and not in the web browser.

On the other hand, if I do the same from a Stack Overflow page in
the mobile web browser then the corresponding comment/posting is opened
within the web browser.

I think that links in the web browser should also be opened in the web
browser. That the behaviour is different depending on from which
community the link is clicked makes no sense (to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I can tell, this is how Apple's Universal Links are designed:

- Going from unsupported path `/` to supported path `/questions/349369` within a single domain does not cause the app to open.
- Going from one domain to a supported path on another domain does cause the app to open.

The fact that Stack Exchange encompasses multiple domains causes the problem and unfortunately I don't know of a fix for this that doesn't involve shutting off Universal Links for Stack Overflow.  It looks like iOS 11+ no longer supports disabling universal links for a specific app (for better or for worse, because the mechanic was weird).

You can, however, force a page to open in the browser by long-pressing it to bring up the menu.  This gives you three choices:

- "Open", navigates to the page in browser.
- "Open in new tab", same but in a new tab.
- "Open in Stack Overflow", opens in the app, same as if you clicked on it.

Comment: How do you re-enable Universal Links when that bar doesn't appear in Safari?

Comment: @jjz I updated the answer since that functionality went away in iOS 11.  I don't think you can disable Universal Links anymore, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't be appearing.